# attaching three handles onto three manifold with boundary

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, geometric-topology

Assume $M$ is a three-manifold with a single component of the boundary, if we assume that $S^2$ diffeomorphic to some submanifold $S\subset \partial M$.Prove $S$ has to be the whole boundary.

I can deal with the two manifold case, if $S^1$ diffeomorphic to some submanifold $S\subset \partial M$ (with $\partial M$ has one component) ,since the boundary of $M$ is compact smooth 1-manifold,by the classification result, therefore $\partial M$ has to diffeomorphic to $S^1$ or interval.Therefore  $S$ has to be the whole circle.(since interval does not diffeomorphic to the circle).

For three-manifold case, I can argue as follows, since $S^2$ is a two dimensinal manifold without a boundary,by diffeomorphism invariance of the boundary, the two dimension submanifold $S\subset \partial M$ do not have boundary,therefore $S$ is an open subset of $\partial M$.However I have no idea how to argue that $S = \partial M$? Since topologically the $\partial M$ needs not even to looks like the $S^2$?

Comment: If $M$ is a three-manifold with a single component boundary, then the boundary is a connected closed two-manifold. So you can apply the classification of $2$-manifolds and $S^2$ is the only two-manifold that contains a copy of $S^2$.

Comment: How can I arguement that toru or real projective plane does not contains an open subset that looks like $S^2$? @quarague

Comment: Thank you , topologically closed two manifold looks like $S^2$ or 
connect sum of  torus of real proejctive spaces.

Comment: Oh I see ,since torus and real projective plane are connected, and $S^2$ is open subset which is also compact, it has to be the whole torus or real projective plane, which is impossible